# Custom verifier on DevForce 2012

Tags: devforce

Our SL project uses DevForce 2010 and we used custom verification attributes. There is a CustomVerificationAttribute.tt file that has buddy classes for entities that need it (for mandatory fields in the database). We also created a custom NullEntityVerifierAttribute used to decorate the property in the edmx designer file.

Just managed to upgrade to DevForce 2012 with 2010 compatibility, updated codebase on what needs updating. Everything seems to be working, except those custom verifiers.

Is there anything about Custom verifiers that changed between then and now?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to checkout http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ for existing answers to you question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We didn't explicitly change anything with custom verifiers, but there were a lot of other changes, including namespace changes and features moved to different assemblies.  First take a look at your CustomVerificationAttribute.tt to make sure it's using the correct assembly references and namespaces.  Next, use of the MetadataType attribute and buddy classes during code generation is a bit weird, and actually requires that you build twice.  Also look at the output window during build and code gen to see if DevForce wrote any errors.  If there's still a problem and you're licensed for DF support, you can open a support request via the IdeaBlade web site.

Comment: I decided to take the path of customizing the template to decorate properties with a custom verifier attribute that has been in the original project. Struggled a bit but I think I've got my bearing now. Thank you for replying though to let me know that other than namespace and features getting moved, you're not doing something totally different for custom verifiers .